# The service principal name (delegation) configuration has been set incorrectly (Ms Dynamics NAV)

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I am getting this error on client computers when they try to open Ms Dynamics Nav.

[image: Navison Error]

I have read some of the suggestions online and from what i have gathered, I am suspecting that the Ms Dynamics server might be encountering the "*The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed*" error. 
i need some bit of advice here; 
I have 2 servers here; One running the AD services (Server1) and the other running the MS Dynamics server (Server2)-Ms Dynamics Nav 2013R2 where users are authenticated from the AD server. The Error started on Monday (30th April)and after rebooting the two servers, the error cleared and recurred again yesterday (Wednesday 2nd May) at around 11 Am and today (3rd May) at around 10:30am.

Ordinarily when a client computer encounters the "*The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed*" error, we remove it from the domain and then add it back and the error clears.

My question is: **What would be the impact (On Nav Users and the Nav server)of removing the Ms Dynamics Nav server from the domain and then adding it back**?

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully removed and added back the server to the domain and so far so Good. Users are able to login to the system without challenges. I will keep you posted on whether it resolved the error completely.